# loading mnist fashion dataset with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I copied and pasted tensorflow's official Basic classification: Classify images of clothing code https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification

```py
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

and ran it. Upon running it printed a load of gibberish and wouldn't stop (almost like when you accidentally put a print in a while loop):

```
    Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
    
        8192/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 6s
       98304/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 14s
      106496/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 27s
      417792/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 10s
      425984/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 13s
```

so I terminated it. The above is just a VERY small portion of what printed. I ran it again, only to get an error straight away.

```
    line 7, in <module>
        (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
      File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\datasets\fashion_mnist.py", line 82, in load_data
        imgpath.read(), np.uint8, offset=16).reshape(len(y_train), 28, 28)
      File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\gzip.py", line 292, in read
        return self._buffer.read(size)
      File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\gzip.py", line 498, in read
        raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached")
```

I checked a similar question, deleted the dataset causing this error and ran it again. I waited out the gibberish it was printing out and waited for it to finish running, only for it to prematurely terminate after about 30 minutes with this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 275, in get_file
        urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
      File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 286, in urlretrieve
        raise ContentTooShortError(
    urllib.error.ContentTooShortError: <urlopen error retrieval incomplete: got only 9191424 out of 26421880 bytes>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\david\Documents\DAVID\Documents\Education\Computer Science\Extra stuff\Machine learning\Neural networks\ep.2.py", line 7, in <module>
        (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
      File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\datasets\fashion_mnist.py", line 75, in load_data
        paths.append(get_file(fname, origin=base + fname, cache_subdir=dirname))
      File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 279, in get_file
        raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
    Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz: None -- retrieval incomplete: got only 9191424 out of 26421880 bytes
```

I've tried deleting that dataset many times and each time I run the code the same thing happens again and again.

I can't find any forums or stack overflows on what to do when this happens, any help would be appreciated.

TL;DR what do I do to load a MNIST dataset when copying and pasting tensorflow's tutorial code leads to errors?

Comment: Run it again, it clearly says that the download did not complete correctly, it could be a problem with your local internet connection

Answer (score 1):

Look `%USERPROFILE%\.keras\datasets` folder and remove the mnist related files and folder

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that, sorry I should've put that in the original post.

Comment: I removed the `fashion-mnist` folder. I executed the code and halted before completion. I removed the folder again, and the keras started downloading again from the beginning. It is worked without any errors.

Comment: Have you ever ran it and gotten the weird print: Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
    
        8192/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 6s
       98304/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 14s
      106496/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 27s
      417792/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 10s
      425984/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 13s?

Comment: I stopped the kernel while downloading and then removed `fashion-mnist` folder. Files are downloaded successfully. Something breaks your download operation, maybe proxy or internet connection problem. Have you tried to restart your computer?

Comment: What do you mean by stopping the kernel? And restarting my laptop was the first thing I tried, just tried it again now as well (deleting the fashion-minst folder before) and it still didn't work. My internet connection has been fine the whole time I can watch streams and play online games etc.

Comment: I have stopped the downloading operation while some data is downloaded but it is not completed yet. So I killed the python kernel to break the downloading. Have you tried to download another dataset like `tf.keras.datasets.cifar10` ?

Comment: I just tried that dataset and the exact same thing happened

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226531/discussion-between-smail-durmaz-and-mof).

Answer (score 0):

Someone with more knowledge on this might have an actual answer or reason for this, but for me after a long discussion with Ismail we concluded there was just something wrong with my pc or python setup or something, the solution for me was just to use google's colab or any other python shell but IDLE.